# Adding custom WKT in MapInfow.proj

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo, well-known-text

How can I add a custom WKT projection in MapInfow.proj file?

Below is my WKT parameters:

```
WKT
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unnamed",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Transverse Mercator",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",121,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.99995,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Proj4
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.99995 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
Extent
Extent not known
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be quite similar to a standard Universal Transverse Mercator projector based on WGS84.

I'd suggest copying the existing "UTM Zone 50, Northern Hemisphere (WGS 84)" projection string and modifying it.

The original look like this:

```
"UTM Zone 50, Northern Hemisphere (WGS 84)\p32650", 8, 104, 7, 117, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0
```

And I think the changes you need to make are these:

- Remove the EPSG code (\p32650)
- Change the Longitude of natural origin from 117 to 121
- Change the Scale factor from 0.9996 to 0.99995
- Change the name of the coordinate system. I used 'UTM Zone 50.5' as it seems to lie between zone 50 and 51

The new line should look like this:

```
"UTM Zone 50.5, Northern Hemisphere (WGS 84)", 8, 104, 7, 121, 0, 0.99995, 500000, 0
```

Test it and let us know if it works